# How to create a URL for templateView?

Tags: python, django

How can I write a url for a form using `TemplateView`. I wrote a method to validate and pass the company details through `form`. Using that `form` object that I'm trying to access the HTML fields.

*Form.py*

```
class CompanyDetailsForm(forms.Form):
    class meta:
        fields = ['company_name','contact_person','employee_count','email','mobile_number']
        widgets = {
            'comment':Textarea(attrs={'cols':30,'rows':5}),
        }

    company_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'company Name'}))
    contact_person = forms.CharField(max_length=100,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Contact Person'})) 
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=100,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Email'}))
    employee_count = forms.CharField(max_length=100,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Number Of Employee'}))
    mobile_number = forms.CharField(max_length=100,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Mobile Number'}))
```

*View.py*

```
class GetCompanyView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "astra/company_details.html"
    form = CompanyDetailsForm()

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form']=self.form
        return context

    def company_details(request):
        if request.method =="POST":
            form = CompanyDetailsForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                company_name = form.cleaned_data['company_name']
                contact_person = form.cleaned_data['contact_person']
                email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                employee_count = form.cleaned_data['employee_count']
                mobile_number = form.cleaned_data['mobile_number']
                try:
                    form.save()
                    send_mail(company_name,contact_person,email,employee_count,mobile_number,['salesastra500@gmail.com'])
                except BadHeaderError:
                        return BadHeaderError
            return render(request,'astra/company_details.html',{'form':form})
        else:
            return render(request,'astra/company_details.html')
```

I want to run my `company_details.html` file using `TemplateView`. I'm not able to write the url for same. Plz suggest

Comment: what did you try in your `urls.py`?

Comment: Why are you using a template view rather than a create view, which will handle your form for you?

Comment: from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from . import views

app_name = 'astra'

urlpatterns =[
    path('',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='astra/index.html'),name='home'),
    path('contact',views.ContactView.as_view()),
    path('company',views.GetCompanyView.as_view()),
    
    
]

Answer (score 2):

TemplateView only have get method

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request,self.template_name, {'form': self.form})
```

if you have get and post methods use FormView